# APEX: How to put Map inside map

Tags: apex

I have a Map defined inside another Map. I am trying to put values inside both the Maps but Sub Map is not working. Please suggest.

Code-

```
Map<Id,Map<string,string> myMap = new Map<Id,Map<string,string>();

1st try -
myMap.put(obj.Id,new new Map<string,string>('value1','value2')); NOT WORKING

2nd try -
myMap.get(obj.Id);.putAll('value1','value2'); NOT WORKING
```

Thank you

Comment: Please use relevant tags only. This question is not related to `marketing-cloud` or `scheduled-apex`

Comment: Oh. Can you help me with this question please, David?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, Maps are defined with two data types, such that we would express this in generic terms written with a unique letter for each data type involved: `Map<T, U>`, or as the documentation states: `Map<T1, T2>`. I prefer the classic nomenclature, but choose whichever you feel you understand better.

In your case, `T` is `Id`, and `U` is `Map<T′, U′>`. `T′` and `U′` are the type `String`. If you remember that, it should be easier to construct complicated types in the future:

```
Map< T ,            U          >
Map< Id, Map<   T′  ,   U′   > >
Map< Id, Map< String, String > >
```

Second, to populate nested structures, you have to put them inside each other. In other words, before you can populate a value in the inner map, the outer map must have the object created first. To create most objects, we use the `new` keyword. One `new` is one new object.

When we create a new object, we call a *constructor*, which can take zero or more parameters to configure the initial state of the object. They are normal methods, which means we need to pass in any parameters, like we would any other method. `new Map<Id, Map<String, String>>()`, for example, constructs a new object with the compound data type `Map<Id, Map<String, String>>`.

So, to populate such a Map, we would do something like:

```
Map<Id, Map<String, String>> myMap = new Map<Id, Map<String, String>>();
myMap.put(obj.Id, new Map<String, String>());
myMap.get(obj.Id).put('value1','value2');
```

Note that `put` displaces the previous value if it exists, so we normally check first:

```
Map<String, String> myMapValue = myMap.get(obj.Id);
if(myMapValue == null) {
  myMapValue = new Map<String, String>();
  myMap.put(obj.Id, myMapValue);
}
myMapValue.put('value1','value2');
```

You can initialize a Map with the `{}` constructor format:

```
Map<Id, Map<String, String>> myMap = new Map<Id, Map<String, String>> {
  obj.Id => new Map<String, String> {
    'value1' => 'value2'
  }
};
```

Notice how there are two `new` keywords. We are still creating new objects, just placing one inside the other initially. The `=>` operator simply means "key => value." This is the only use of `=>` in Apex at this time.

Note that `putAll` is used to put a bunch of values inside the map at once. It requires that the parameter provided is the same type as `U` from our example above.

```
Map<Id, Map<String, String>> myMap = new Map<Id, Map<String, String>>();
Map<String, String> params = new Map<String, String>();
params.put('value1','value2');
myMap.put(obj.Id, new Map<String, String>());
myMap.get(obj.Id).putAll(params);
```

Comment: That nicely explained sfdcfox. Now, I am concerned about Map values getting displaced because I realized I need a List of Map instead. it should be Map<T, List<Map<T,U>>>. How should we keep adding map values to that list having Id as key in the parent Map?

Comment: @PraveenBehera That's going to just be an extra step: check if the `List<Map<T′, U′>>` exists for the key, else put a new `List<Map<T′, U′>>`, then figure out which index to use, then create a new `Map<T′, U′>` and add it to the list. Without specific knowledge of what you're trying to do, I can't provide much more detail. While this was a good question, I'd suggest you ask a more specific question, as described in the [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) site.

Comment: Your answer helped me to figure out a way, instead of using additional List instance, I am using Map only. Thanks this was really good one to me. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    Map<Id,Map<string,string> myMap = new Map<Id,Map<string,string>{}
myMap.put(obj.Id, new map<string, string>{'test' => 'test'});
```

More details here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521740/apex-map-within-a-map